# com.google.api.services.drive.model.File.getPermissions() returns null

Tags: file, api, permissions, get, google-drive-api

com.google.api.services.drive.model.File.getPermissions() returns null instead of a list of permission resources even if the file has permissions. The same fileId when used in com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Permissions.list(String fileId) returns the right list of  permissions. I was hoping to avoid a second API call just to get the permissions, by calling getPermissions() on the already retrieved File object.

Does anybody have any clue on why the getPermissions() returns null ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with this code:

```
drive.files().list().execute().getItems()
```

It turns out that the Google drive api doesn't, by default, get all the information for each of the files returned.

In my case, I fixed it by specifying which fields I wanted:

```
final String fields = "items(id,labels/trashed,owners/emailAddress,permissions(emailAddress,name,role),title)";
drive.files().list().setFields(fields).execute().getItems()
```

I used the "fields editor" [near the bottom of this page](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) to create the fields string.